# How to access meta tables of oracle database from postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, oracle11g, postgresql-9.3, oracle-fdw

My oracle database(11.2) and postgresql database(9.3.5)

My requirement is to extract the data from oracle database to postgresql database
for that purpose i used oracle_fdw(foreign data wrapper concept).

I could extracted all the data of particular schema(oracle db).

I am able to extract the data of normal tables.but i am not able to access the meta tables
like all_tab_columns

I created server and user and provided server details and user mapping details(sys privileges)
while accessing time it's giving me error

ERROR: session for foreign table "all_tab_columns" cannot be authenticated
SQL state: HV00N
Detail: ORA-12571: TNS:packet writer failure

Comment: What if you create a view over `all_tab_columns` and select from it instead?

Comment: Hi Kouber Saparev.that is not possible we have to declare in postgres database exact same structure what oracle object having..then only we can do any thing